# Finding out what .* inside a regex matched?

Tags: java, regex

Hey guys i have a new problem.

I have a dynamically created String, that contains a placeholder !fruit!. I then want to find any Strings that match this String. Therefore i do the following:

```
String s = "A Basket of !fruit! was lost";
String toCompare "A Basket of Apples was lost";
if (toCompare.match(s.replace("!fruit!", ".*"))) //Yes everycharacter is a Fruit :-P 
   //do something
```

I now want to know what the .* matched against (in this case "Apples") and i am kinda clueless on how to go about this...

Comment: Not sure what your question is: . matches any character, and the * tells the regex to match the previous expression (in this case the . ) 0 or more times.

Comment: Do you control how this `!fruit!` string is created?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis it's outside data :-(

Comment: (Don't put spaces between `@` and a user's name. They won't get notified.)

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis :-)

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a capturing group (`(.*)`), and use the [Pattern API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to get the group from the found match:

```
    String s = "A Basket of !fruit! was lost";
    String toCompare = "A Basket of Apples was lost";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s.replace("!fruit!", "(.*)"));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toCompare);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need the regex to define a capturing group, which is done with parenthesis: `s.replace("!fruit!", "(.*)")`.

Then, you need to use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) instead of just the plain `String.match`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s.replace("!fruit!", "(.*)"));
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(toCompare);
if (m.matches()) {
  String fruit = m.group(1);
}
```

---

To be a bit more robust, you should also watch out for `s` strings that themselves have "special" regular expression characters, or don't contain "!fruit!" at all.

For instance, what if `s = "Was a basket (or something) of !fruit! lost?"`. In that case, the first matching group will be of `(or something)`, the parentheses won't be matched against (since they're special characters in regexes), and the `?` will affect the `t` rather than matching a question mark. This would match:

```
toCompare = "Was a basket or something of apples los";
```

... with `matcher.group(1)` being `"or something"`, rather than `"apples"` (which will be in `matcher.group(2)`).

Solving this problem generally is going to be just a bit harder. You should basically split the string on `!fruit!`, use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) on each side, and then splice in a `"(.*)"`. (`Pattern.quote` takes a string and returns a string which, when treated as a regular expression, will match the first string literally. For instance, passing in `"foo?"` will return `"foo\?".)

```
String[] splits = s.split("!fruit!");
if (splits.length != 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no '!fruit!' specified");
}
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    Pattern.quote(splits[0]) +  "(.*)" + Pattern.quote(splits[1]));
...
```

Comment: This sounds solid, is it group(1) or group(0)? Thank you for the fast and competent answer. I knew i could find the position of matches, but had no clue about the group feature.

Comment: You want `group(1)`.  `group(0)` is always the entire match ("A Basket of Apples was lost", in this case).

Comment: It's `group(1)`. `group(0)` refers to the _whole_ matched string, and is primarily useful when you use `matcher.find()` (which looks for any matching substring) rather than `matcher.matches()` (which requires that the whole string matches, in which case `group(0)` is just `s`).